# How to fix a wrong number of arguments error (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby

The code below is giving me an `ArgumentError` and I can't figure out the problem.

The challenge comes from the Advent of Code, day 3.

```
require 'set'

x, y = 0
visited = Set.new

def move(dir)
  case move
  when ">"
    x += 1
  when "<"
    x -= 1
  when "^"
    y += 1
  when "v"
    y -= 1
  end
end

def visit(x,y)
  unless visited.include?([x,y])
    visited << [x,y]
  end
end

a_file = File.open("day3a_directions.txt", "r")
a_file.each_line("\n") do |line|
  line.each_char do |dir|
    move(dir)
    visit(x,y)
  end  
end

puts visited.length
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
day3a.rb:6:in `move': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
    from tmp.rb:7:in `move'
    from tmp.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from tmp.rb:27:in `each_char'
    from tmp.rb:27:in `block in <main>'
    from tmp.rb:26:in `each_line'
    from tmp.rb:26:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you add the stack trace?

Comment: Ruby doesn't have a "Wrong argument error." Please edit your post to include the exact error message including the line number and the stack trace.

Comment: P.S. I can see one problem with your code: In `visit` you call `visited.include?`, but `visited` does not exist in that scope.

Comment: Yeah I made the variables global. See my post below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in your code in the definition of `move`, here:

```
def move(dir)
  case move
  when ">"
  ...
```

Should be:

```
def move(dir)
  case dir
  when ">"
  ...
```

Also, I might add that you're circumventing the whole point of `Set` by checking if an element exists before adding it. This is built into the class already.

Comment: Thanks guys. I fixed the case error and I made the variables global so that fixed the errors. Now I am just getting the wrong answer so there must be a problem with my logic. I'll work on that.